# Create Array From VBA Recordset

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am in need of populating a VBA Array with the fields that fit the criteria in my `IF` statement.  I can not wrap my head around creating the array from the recordset, it seems like a completely different world than a "normal" array to me.  Here is what I have:

```
Function AlterTable()

Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("___TestTable")
For Each fld In rs2.Fields
If fld.Name <> "ID" Then
If FieldTypeName(fld) <> "Text" Then
    Debug.Print fld.Name  
    'Populate Array Here
  End If
End If
Next

Set fld = Nothing
rs2.Close

End Function
```

Comment: to move from Recordset to array you could use simple method: `rs2.GetRows()`. However, first you need to create correct recordset results based on SQL query where you can exclude `ID field` and others of `Text type`.

Comment: @KazimierzJawor - so it's even bigger than what I initially thought.  Thank you for posting to allow me a starting point for google :)

Comment: A really *fresh* answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485788/dynamically-populate-vba-array/41486069#41486069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following function to generate the SQL required to extract what you desire and then use `.GetRows()` from this.  It uses ADO, so you'll need to add the reference to ADO.  Based on the above you could use this to generate the `INSERT INTO from (function return)`

something like `docmd.runsql "INSERT INTO tbl_TEST_Clone " & GEN_SQL_TABLE("tbl_test")`

```
Option Explicit

Function GEN_SQL_TABLE(strTableName As String) As String

Dim r As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rKeys As New ADODB.Recordset

Set r = CurrentProject.Connection.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, _
                Array(Empty, Empty, strTableName, Empty))

r.Filter = "[DATA_TYPE]<>" & adWChar

Set rKeys = CurrentProject.Connection.OpenSchema(adSchemaPrimaryKeys, _
        Array(Empty, Empty, strTableName))

While Not r.EOF
    If Not rKeys.BOF Then rKeys.MoveFirst
    rKeys.Filter = "[COLUMN_NAME]='" & r.Fields("COLUMN_NAME").value & "'"
    If rKeys.EOF Then
        GEN_SQL_TABLE = _
            GEN_SQL_TABLE & IIf(Len(GEN_SQL_TABLE) > 0, ",", "") & _
            r.Fields("COLUMN_NAME").value
    End If
    rKeys.Filter=""
    r.MoveNext
Wend

GEN_SQL_TABLE = "SELECT " & GEN_SQL_TABLE & " FROM " & strTableName

r.Close
rKeys.Close

Set r = Nothing
Set rKeys = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: This looks like a good function to use, but on this project I am pretty tied to DAO and I don't believe you can use both ADO & DAO on one database.  Def saving to a text file to store for later :)

Comment: You can do both, I've prefixed with the class name `ADODB`, say your table has 100 fields, all non-text, your method will do an insert 100 times per row.  Look at this, one SQL operation, whether you run on DAO runsql or ADO's execute. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment providing direction on where to steer by @KazimierzJawor -> 
This was the syntax that I was able to come up with that accomplished what I was after.  (Need to add error handling, but this is 1st run through)

```
Function Blue()
Dim CreateTableSQL As String
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Set db = CurrentDb()

CreateTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE [GreenSocks] (FieldPK COUNTER CONSTRAINT PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY, fieldname TEXT);"
db.Execute CreateTableSQL

Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("___TestTable")
For Each fld In rs2.Fields
    If fld.Name <> "ID" And fld.Name <> "Store Number" Then
        If FieldTypeName(fld) <> "Text" Then
            Debug.Print fld.Name

                strSQL = "INSERT INTO GreenSocks (fieldname) VALUES ('" & fld.Name & "' );"
                DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

        End If
    End If
Next

Set fld = Nothing
rs2.Close

strSQL = "select fieldname from GreenSocks"

Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
For Each fld In rs3.Fields

    Debug.Print fld.Value

    secondSQL = "ALTER TABLE __TestTable ALTER COLUMN [" & fld.Value & "] TEXT(40);"

    DoCmd.RunSQL secondSQL

 Next

  Set fld = Nothing
  rs3.Close

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim colNames() As Variant
colNames = Array("Employee", "Client")
'rs.MoveFirst
Dim data() As Variant ' Two dimensional array
data = rs.GetRows(Fields:=colNames)
' data(0,5) is Employee for 6th row in recordset
```